# Problems with memory consuming while canvas operations (fillRect() etc.) in Chrome etc

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, gwt

I have an application written with GWT which looks a little bit like a Gantt chart. It works well but sometimes I have some problems with the memory usage of the application.. To paint the chart I use one big canvas, for example width 10000 px and height 2500 px. When I paint my chart initially everything is fine (memory usage JavaScript in Chrome 50 MB, memory usage over all in Chrome 150 MB (from Chrome task manager)).
The problem starts with repainting some parts of the chart, for example it is possible to select something, that means the clicked rect should get another color. In that case I repaint everything new which intersects with my rect, for example 5 other rects with a size of 40 x 10 px overall. And this is really memory consuming, JavaScript memory usage is nearly fixed but the memory usage over all increases by some 100 MB. Why that? If my canvas is smaller, for example 1500 x 1000 px and I do th same operation the memory usage increases also but only for 50 MB.
That's why I think the problem has nothing to do with my coding in JavaScript/GWT, it has something to do how chromes handles the painting on the canvas. Is there a possibilty to see, what consumes all the memory? With the Chrome dev tools I can only see all the JavaScript stuff. But the memory usage of JavaScript is nearly fixed. I read something about the trace tool inside chrome. But this is really hard to understand if you have no knowledge about the internals of chrome. What else could be the reason for the memory usage?
If it is the repainting on the canvas, what should I do? I read something about canvas/rendering strategies:

1. background rendering (create a second canvas of the size of changes, paint all changes on this canvas and place this one in the original, big one)
2. multi canvas (create a second canvas of the size of changes, paint all changes on this canvas and place this canvas on the right position on top of the orignal, big one as a second canvas in the html page),
3. one canvas which fits to the screen size and you paint only a small view of the hole chart and when you "scroll" you have to repaint the missing parts (I think the chrome trace tool works like this, does'nt it?)

First would be quite easy to implement it in my application, 2. is a little bit more complicated and 3. is quite difficult. Would one of the strategies solve my problem? If it is strategy c), what is the best way to implement it? Is there any support from the GWT framework or HTML5/canvas itself? What's about the usage of a scroll panel, because the canvas has a fixed size? How the trace tool does it?

Thanks a lot, Szdnez

Comment: I ran across the same problem a couple of years ago and had to go with 3. It only happens in Chrome, oddly, Firefox and IE11 were fine.

Answer (score 0):

Image size 10000 by 2500 uses 10000*2500*4 bytes (100mb) minimum just to exist. Depending on how you use that image and the capabilities of the GPU and its RAM there will be more used.

Without code it really is impossible to say where the memory usage is and where it is wasteful and unnecessary.

Chromes task manager shows total memory used, this includes memory no longer referenced by your code and simply waiting for GC (garbage collection, part of the memory management system) to clean up. If required the browser will force GC to clean up. The memory usage (as seen in the task manager) can go well above 100MB while in fact you are only using 100mb.

Answer (score 0):

the total usage of 100-150 MB is not the problem. The problem ist, hat I have some operations in my code, which additional uses some 100 MB.
After a lot of try and error and un-/commenting line by line I found the bottleneck (I hope I found it). Before I redraw the rectangle for example, I do some clipping to be shure, that only one special region is redrawed (a simplified code example):

```
context2d.save()

context2d.rect( x, y, width, height );
context2d.clip();

redrawRectangle();

context2d.restore;
```

With this code the memory usage increases by 200 MB. If I skip the clipping:

```
// context2d.rect( x, y, width, height );
// context2d.clip();
```

memory usage is nearly steady. In this case I do not really need the clipping. But why it is such "expensive"? Are there other possibilies to do the same?

Thanks, Szdnez

Comment: It's getting more strange for me. In my test case with clipping I drawed the rect over the whole canvas. Now I tried it without clipping so I have to draw the rectangle in the same size as the clipping before. Now the memory problem is back. If I just change the size of the rect in my new code to the size of the canvas there is no memory problem. It looks like, that there is a memory problem when you draw something that is smaller than the canvas.